# Filter or subset based on NOT greater than AND NOT smaller than in R

Tags: r, subset

I want to subset an interval on the lower end as well as on the upper end along a range of numbers in a variable. My question is how can I subset or filter based on NOT greater than AND NOT smaller than in R? I looked up the relational operators `?'>'` and there is nothing like `!>` or `!>=`. Then I found that it is possible with `!between()` from the `dplyr` package but I cannot figure out how to negate this in base R. How would you do that? Something like `!(x[x >= left & x <= right])` doesn't work...

```r
require(dplyr)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
require(ggplot2)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
x <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = 1000)
d <- tibble(X = x, Y = x^3)

### THIS WORKS
(d %>% 
  filter(!between(X, -2, 2)) -> d_sub)
#> # A tibble: 600 x 2
#>        X     Y
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 -5    -125 
#>  2 -4.99 -124.
#>  3 -4.98 -124.
#>  4 -4.97 -123.
#>  5 -4.96 -122.
#>  6 -4.95 -121.
#>  7 -4.94 -121.
#>  8 -4.93 -120.
#>  9 -4.92 -119.
#> 10 -4.91 -118.
#> # ... with 590 more rows

### PLOT TO CONFIRM
(d_sub%>% 
  ggplot(aes(X,Y)) + geom_point())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to negate anything. You can do `(x <= -2) | (x >= 2)`

E.g.

```
X= -10:10

X[(X <= -2) | (X >= 2)]
#[1] -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

Which is the same as

```
X[!(X >-2 & X <2)]
#[1] -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

Comment: Dang... so simple! I was so focused on not greater than that I didn't even consider "or" in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In `base R`,  we can use `subset` and specify only the unquoted column names

```
d_sub2 <- subset(d, !(X >=-2 & X <2))
identical(d_sub, d_sub2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or with `[`

```
d_sub3 <- d[!(d$X >= -2 & d$X < 2),]
```

Comment: Great answer too (+1) but I accepted @dww answer since he also brought up the "or" approach.