# Using not grater than for subsetting data in R data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, boolean, boolean-logic

In the dataframe `df`, I only want to keep the rows where `A` is less than 6. I tried following a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997164/filter-or-subset-based-on-not-greater-than-and-not-smaller-than-in-r) but I get a set with no data.

```
set.seed(111)
df <- data.frame(sp = rep(c("A","B"), each = 10),
val = rnorm(20,5,5))

df <- df[!(df[df$sp == "A",]$val > 6), ]

result NULL or empty data
```

Comment: Try this:  `df <- df[df$A < 6, ]`

Comment: There is no `female` column in your data.frame.

Comment: @kmm gahhhhhhhhh. my bad. was trying to generate a dummy code

Comment: @DanY, please post as answer? (Also, `subset(df, A < 6)` or `dplyr::filter(df, A < 6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Base R implementation:

```
df <- df[df$A < 6, ]
```